# MongoDB Logical operators in go not working

Tags: mongodb, go

I am attempting to query documents in my mongo database. I've tried each condition individually and that works fine, however when using the `and` operator nothing is selected. I want to be able to specify a range of time (in unix timestamp format) and return all events that fall in between. Its also important that I can specify a `userid` so only events created by a single user will be selected.

```
// Specify the filter
filter := bson.D{
    {
        "$and",
        bson.A{
            bson.D{{"start", bson.D{{"$gte", datamap.Schedule.Start}}}},
            bson.D{{"end", bson.D{{"lte", datamap.Schedule.End}}}},
            bson.D{{"userid", datamap.Schedule.UserID}},
        },
    },
}

cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a test myself, and confirm that it's the typo below to blame:

```golang
bson.D{{"end", bson.D{{"lte", datamap.Schedule.End}}}},
```

`lte` should be `$lte`.

Without the leading `$`, the generated query is:

```json
{
  "$and": [
    { "start": { "$gte": 123 } },
    { "end": { "lte": 456 } },
    { "userid": "the-id" }
  ]
}
```

It means that, besides other expressions, the documents should have an embedded document `end` whose `lte` field value is `456`. Obviously, there is not a document has the field `end.lte`, so nothing is selected.